# Fanless SSD portable hard disk supporting USB 3.2 in the price of up to 100$

Tags: hard-disk

What is your recommendation for a fanless SSD portable ("external") hard disk supporting USB 3.2 in the price of up to 100$?

SSD here can also be SSD-NVMe.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a combo like this [enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MNFH1PX) with a standard [NVMe drive](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09QV692XY). It will be much more performance for the money and will be more versitile, in that you can swap out the drive.